# Symfony flush not working in action

Tags: symfony, doctrine, flush

Flush function not working in a specific function. This is the function for which it's not working:

```
 /**
   * @Route("/mob/user/ma")
   */
  public function setMaAction(Request $request)
  {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find(1);


    $date = $trainer->getDate();
    $date->modify('+30 day');
    $user->setDate($date);

//dump($user->getDate()); ===> return date 30 days after today! correct...
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response("A");
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you get an error or is the date change not persisted?

Comment: Where is the `$trainer` variable set ?

Comment: no need to persist the `$user` if it comes your database